# Alias for ActiveRecord columns in 'where' function

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an external readonly DB. Where is columns like 'LastName', 'CreateDate' etc. I want to make some kind of alias for it. For example:

```
MyModel.select('LastName AS last_name').where(last_name: 'Somebody')
```

I can't modify structure of DB and I doesn't want to process result of query. In a perfect case ActiveRecord must process 'LastName' and 'last_name' in any function as a absolutely equivalent column.

Answer (score 0):

You must do the operation for SQL and for Rails.

```
class MyModel

  def last_name=(v)
    return self.LastName=(v)
  end

  def last_name(reload = false)
     return LastName(reload)
  end

  scope :with_last_name, -> {
     select("#{MyModel.table_name}.*, LastName AS last_name")
  }
end
```

Then, you can use it like this :

```
MyModel.with_last_name.where(:last_name => "Somebody")
```

**edit**

You're right.

An other solution is to define your own `where` method, like this :

```
def translate(h)
   return { :created_at => 'CREATEDAT' }[h] || h
end

def self.my_where(opts)
  opts2 = opts.inject({}) do |o,(h,v)|
    o[translate(h)] = v; o
  end
  return where(opts2)
end
```

Then, a call to `M.my_where(:created_at => v)` will call `M.where('CREATEDAT' => v)`.

But you have to keep in mind that every other methods (having, group, and a lot) will not work.

Comment: This is a crutch. I need a method for mass redefine columns in ActiveRecord. This code: `MyModel.select("MyTable.CREATEDDATETIME AS created_at").where(created_at: DateTime.now)` doesn't work for me.It raise "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Invalid column name 'created_at'". I use Rails3, DB - MSSQL.

Comment: @user3240646 You're true. I edited my solution. Bad.